# Password Hash function port from python to .net 8

Tags: python, .net, hash, cryptography

we have an old software system written in python which uses the following password hash functions:

```py
import hashlib, binascii, os
 
def hash_password(password):
    """Hash a password for storing."""
    salt = hashlib.sha256(os.urandom(60)).hexdigest().encode('ascii')
    pwdhash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', password.encode('utf-8'), 
                                salt, 100000)
    pwdhash = binascii.hexlify(pwdhash)
    return (salt + pwdhash).decode('ascii')
 
def verify_password(stored_password, provided_password):
    """Verify a stored password against one provided by user"""
    salt = stored_password[:64]
    stored_password = stored_password[64:]
    pwdhash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', 
                                  provided_password.encode('utf-8'), 
                                  salt.encode('ascii'), 
                                  100000)
    pwdhash = binascii.hexlify(pwdhash).decode('ascii')
    return pwdhash == stored_password
```

We tried to migrate this code to .net 8 but couldn't get the right results
=> the generated hash in python is not equal to the generated hash in C#

Does anyone has an idea what could be wrong with our approach?

Here is what we've tried:

```cs
public string HashPassword(string password)
    {
        var salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GenerateRandomString(60));

        using var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password),
            salt,
            100000,
            HashAlgorithmName.SHA512);
        var hashedPassword = pbkdf2.GetBytes(64);

        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(salt.Concat(hashedPassword).ToArray());
    }

    public bool VerifyPassword(string password, string hash)
    {
        var salt = hash[..64];
        var passwordHash = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash[64..]);
        
        using var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password),
            Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt),
            100000,
            HashAlgorithmName.SHA512);
        var hashedPassword = pbkdf2.GetBytes(64);
        
        return hashedPassword.SequenceEqual(passwordHash);
    }

private string GenerateRandomString(int length)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();  
        var random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            double flt = random.NextDouble();
            int shift = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(25 * flt));
            char letter = Convert.ToChar(shift + 65);
            sb.Append(letter);  
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Couldn't get the right results", please clarify. What is `GenerateRandomString` on the .Net side? It looks like it might generate a 60 character string, whereas your code seems to assume that it generates a 64 character string. This would make verification of passwords generated from the .Net side impossible.

Comment: You're not using the password parameter in the `VerifyPassword` function. I can't verify, but it looks like you're mixing up the `provided_password` and `stored_password` in the .net 8 version of `VerifyPassword`.

Comment: Also, in the .NET code, at least the hash is corrupted because of the ASCII decoding (whether the salt is also corrupted depends on (the missing) `GenerateRandomString()`). To fix this and also for compatibility with the Python code, use a hex encoding (like in the Python code) instead of the ASCII decoding.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I updated the question (include `GenerateRandomString`, updated code)

Comment: Don't apply `Random` but a cryptographically secure random number generator for cryptography, e.g. [`RandomNumberGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator?view=net-8.0). Also, the salt generation is unnecessarily cumbersome, just create a 32 bytes salt and hex encode that. Plus, the hex encoding of the hash is still missing, so the data is still corrupted. Make sure to use the same convention on both sides regarding the upper/lower case of the hex digits.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I managed to find a solution.

```
public string HashPassword(string password)
    {
        var salt = HexDigest(SHA256.HashData(RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(30)));

        var hashedPassword = ComputeHmacSha512Hash(password, salt);

        return salt + HexDigest(hashedPassword);
    }

    public bool VerifyPassword(string passwordToVerify, string saltPasswordHash)
    {
        var salt = saltPasswordHash[..64];
        var password = saltPasswordHash[64..];
        
        var hashedPassword = ComputeHmacSha512Hash(passwordToVerify, salt);
        
        return password.SequenceEqual(HexDigest(hashedPassword));
    }

    private static byte[] ComputeHmacSha512Hash(string password, string salt)
    {
        using var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password),
            Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt),
            100000,
            HashAlgorithmName.SHA512);
        return pbkdf2.GetBytes(64);
    }

    private static string HexDigest(byte[] bytes)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    }
```